# Sort list from top to right instead left to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a div with fix width & height.  I need a list that will go from top to bottom and when there is room left in height will go right. The regular way that list works is from to the left to the right and when there is no room in the width there is a line break and continue...

The reason is very simple I need to sort list by ABC and Like:

```text
A   B
ABC BCD
ABD BCE
```

Instead of:

```plain
A ABC ABD
B BCD BCE
```

HTML Structure:

```html
<ul class="lists" id="practice">
  <li><a href="">Arbitration &amp; Mediation</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Banking &amp; Finance</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Capital Markets</a></li>
  <li><a href="">China Desk</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Class Actions &amp; Derivative Suits</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Competition &amp; Antitrust</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Environmental</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you are sorting "lists" then a table might be better.

Comment: Can you provide some code or any other visual?

Comment: Columns, I'd say.See [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) for more about the subject. Note that columns aren't supported very well yet, however.

Answer (score 1):

for younger browser you may use nth-child and float or column-count/width/...

DEMO using your structure : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ifqlz

```
ul, li {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:30em;
  margin:auto;
}
hr {
  clear:both
}
li {overflow:hidden;width:15em;}
.lists li {
  float:left;
  clear:left;
}
.lists li:nth-child(4) ~ li{/* here cause 7/2 (round up/math.ceil()) is 4 */
float:none;
  clear:none;
}
.listsbis {
  column-count:2;
  column-gap:0;
  column-width:15em;
}
```

for older browser you will need javascript or a script like masonry . http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Can you refer to script in JavaScript to support old browsers? Thanks.

Comment: searching on google for masonry, you find the famous :) http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I've download and setup the masonry where is the option to start from top to bottom?